# Deploy meteor app in Azure on Windows

Tags: azure, meteor, deployment

Hello i am have meteor app and want deploy on Azure on Windows, i try it by Meteor Up but can't do it

```
***\project2>npm install -g mup

***\project2>mup init

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------

Empty Project Initialized!

***\project2>mup setup

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------


Started TaskList: Setup (linux) [23.101.74.119] - Installing Node.js events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1000:19)
```

this error in Command Prompt of window from my local system

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error description it might be a connectivity issue. If you could share your mup.json file we might be able to spot the issue there.

Did you create an endpoint on TCP port 80? Check you nodeVersion setting so it corresponds to you Meteor app. The ROOT_URL should be in the format http://[myappname].cloudapp.net.

Using mup logs -n 50 you might detect some clues.

Comment: thanks for answer, but i view this when call: mup logs -n 50

`Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------

events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1000:19)

***\project2>code`